# Formatting for passing HTML div value to JavaScript code

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get value from `div` called `objPath` to `JavaScript` part of my code but I get incorrect formatting like this:

```
uploads/function(e){return x.access(this,function(e){var n=this[0]||
{},r=0,i=this.length;if(e===t)return 1===n.nodeType?n.innerHTML.replace(gt,"")
:t;if(!("string"... and so on
```

Is there any way to get it there better?

```
<div class="page product-details-page">
<div class="page-body">
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Product", new { SeName = Model.SeName }, FormMethod.Post, new {    id = "product-details-form" }))
    {

<div id="objPath">  @Model.ObjPath</div>
<div id="texturePath">  @Model.TexturePath</div>

    }

</div>
</div>
<div>

    <script src="js/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var objPath = $("#objPath").html;
        var str1 = "uploads/";
        var resObjPath = str1.concat(objPath);
        init();

        function init() {

            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
            loader.load(resObjPath, function (object) {
```

Comment: A `div` doesn't have a "value".  What are you actually trying to achieve?  What are the actual runtime values of your variables and how are they incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery already, for objPath, you've *almost* got it right.

To get back the text value contained within the div, you want

`var objPath = $("#objPath").text();`

rather than

`var objPath = $("#objPath").html;`